# Should I use only "exactly same" input shape for transfer learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I trained a CNN model with (5x128x128x3) size of input shape
and I got trained weight of (5x128x128x3)

by the way, I wanna use this weight for training (7x128x128x3) size of input data

So, this is my question
should I use only same shape of input?
I wonder if I can use another size (in this case, 7x128x128x3) of input for transfer learning

````py
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (5, 128, 128, 3) but got arry with shape (7, 128, 128, 3)```
````

Comment: You can use input shape `(None, 128, 128, 3)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down the dimensions **(5x128x128x3)**:

The **first** dimension is the batch size (which was 5 when the original model was trained). This is irrelevant and you can set it to `None` as pointed out in the comments to feed arbitrary sized batches to the model.

The **second to third** dimensions (128x128) are the width and height of the image and you may be able to change these, but it's hard to say for sure without knowing the model architecture and which layer output you're using for transfer learning. The reason you can change these is that 2d convolutional filters are repeated across the 2d dimensions (width and height) of the image, so they will remain valid for different widths and heights (assuming compatible padding). But if you change the 2d dimensions too much, it is possible that the receptive fields of the layers are changed in a way that hurts transfer learning performance. Eg. if the 7th conv layer in the network for 128x128 input can see the entire input image in each activation (a receptive field of 128x128), then if you double the width and height, it won't anymore and the layer may not recognize certain global features.

The **fourth** dimension is the number of channels in the input images and you can't change this, as the filters in the first layer will have 3 weights across the depth dimension.

Comment: Thank you @Agost Biro, I checked again, my mistake is that I was not load "weight" but "model". Now I solve my foolish problem :) and thank you very much for your kind reply :D